# Retropie and raspbian

Tags: raspbian, noobs, retropie

Okay, I’m new to the raspberry pie, so basically what I did was I bought the canakit for the Retropie 3. I followed the instructions, download noobs and downloaded the latest Raspbian Os onto the SD Card then I inserted it to the raspberry pi. The question is, how can I download Retropie onto raspbian? Do I have to delete the content in the SD Card and download Retropie. How can I operate raspbian and Retropie together in the same SD Card or is that impossible. I just wanted to play some retro games....

Thanks,
Morgan

Comment: I have never used Retropie, and don't know if it is possible to install in Raspbian, but you should be able to use with NOOBS (although [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) is more flexible) but I would just buy another SD Card. Unless you already have a large card (32 GB or more) you will need one anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Retropie is a (more or less) normal application.
The Retropie images you can download are actually the application on top of Raspbian Lite.

So yes, you can install Retropie on top of Raspbian. Detailed instructions are on the Retropie website: [Install Retropie on Raspbian](https://retropie.org.uk/docs/Manual-Installation/)